# Why have a separate add and edit view when differences between the two are minor?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I'm wondering this after going through the Zend Framework2 tutorial but it probably applies to MVC logic in general ...

In the tutorial, the examples walk you through having an add view (`module/Album/view/album/album/add.phtml`) and then has you create an edit template (`module/Album/view/album/album/edit.phtml`) in which much of the code is duplicated.  The edit script basically has some extra logic to check for a supplied id but presents the user with the same form.

Now, in similar cases where I haven't entirely used the MVC conventions, I would have a script that would handle both adding and editing options; the logic would assume an 'editing' action if an id was supplied and attempt to retrieve a database record for that id to populate the form fields, plus return an error if an invalid id was supplied.

It seem that a textbook approach to MVC doesn't really encapsulate DRY principles very well if this approach is followed for all database interaction across an application.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around some MVC concepts but is there some reason why an edit action and an add action couldn't (or shouldn't) use the same view template, other than naming conventions?

I see the routing is set up to expect the template names as shown in the tutorial but maybe I could have the view template to render the common form be called `process.phtml` and include that within `add.phtml` and `edit.phtml`. Is that a sensible approach is is there some reasons I should avoid that as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have separate view for edit and add if difference is minor.

1. Use hidden field for record id and set its value in case of Edit and
   set it value blank in case of Add
2. Fetch details of record in case of Edit and populate input fields
   with fetched record data in Case of Edit.

In Zend you can set same view for two actions like :

```
$view = new ViewModel(array('variable'=>$value));
    $view->setTemplate('module/controler/action.phtml'); // path to phtml file under view folder
    return $view;
```

Comment: I assume this would go in the Controller somewhere but I don't quite follow how it would encompass both actions. Would you include this code individually within both action functions?

Comment: Yes you have to specify this code in action whereever you want to use different view apart from ZF2 conventions

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the difference between your `add/edit` views is minor, so your are tempted to have both in the same view.

But, the bigger question is, for how long are the differences going to be minor. Some addition/modification of features, some tweaks here and there and then those differences won't be so minor.

IMO, these are 2 separate functions, hence should be kept in separate concerns(views) from a better readability, and maintenance point of view.

Comment: That may be true in many cases but I've always found when creating forms that the same basic form is presented whether adding or editing; the difference between the two is that during an editing action, pre-existing information is presented within the form and there may be additive features (image previews) but nothing that fundamentally changes the form enough to warrant a duplicated effort. This is my own preference to reduce complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to go for an edit template if you dont want to do that.For both add/edit we can use the same template to avoid duplication of code. if you want to use the same templates for both add and edit you can do it by rendering the specified template.

Example:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('add');
$this->view->mode           =   'edit';
```

Here add.phtml is rendered in edit action and mode specifies that the operation is edit mode and make the changes necessary in the template based on add/edit mode.Thats all

Comment: That makes sense although for semantic reasons, I think I would forego the add template in favor of an edit template (in my mind, adding is a form of editing, but not vice-versa).

Comment: In trying to test this, I was unable to get it to work.  Is this something specific to ZF1?  Note that I am specifically working with ZF2.  The suggestion to use ViewModel() as suggested by another answer appears to be the ZF2 supported way.  Can you confirm if your answer is relevant to ZF2 or is it ZF1 only?

Answer (score 0):

When I first wrote the Albums tutorial, it was helpful to show the two separate actions with their own views in order to help users understand MVC and how it works in Zend Framework.

In my own applications, I have one action and view that handle add and edit in CRUD-type because, as others have noted, the differences are trivial. Sometimes add can be significantly different from updated. In those cases, I separate.